# how to set Environment variables for google cloud sdk ubuntu 12.04

Tags: google-app-engine, ubuntu, gcloud

I had installed google cloud sdk on ubuntu but opted no for updating path variables .and received the following message

please help

how to add path of this inc file permanently tc

Source [/home/usr/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc]
in your profile to add the Google Cloud SDK command line tools to your $PATH

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bash, you can source the file into your profile by adding the following line to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
source /home/usr/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc
```